# TFS 2015 Build builds solution and its projects in wrong order (ASP.NET Core Framework 4.6.1)

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild, .net-core

I have Asp.Net core (Framework 4.6.1) solution with the following structure:

API sln

|-- WebApi.Project_1

```
     |-- Project_2 (Core library, referencing Framework 4.6.1)
                references Project_4 (Core Library, referencing Framework 4.6.1)
     |-- Project_3 (Core library, referencing Framework 4.6.1)
                 references Project_4 (Core Library, referencing Framework 4.6.1)
```

See the "sanitized" project.json files below.

Some notes:

• there is a number of classic (4.6.1 .net) libraries added to the solution but not referenced yet by any other core projects.

• I created the core libraries and manually referenced .net framework 4.6.1 from their json files

•they use x86 platform, specified in project.json -> buildOptions

Everything is built and run OK by using VisualStudio 2015 (either on my local machine or locally on the same build agent server)

The solution build fails when it is built in CI build by TFS 2015 build engine with the following error:

***"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(265,5): Error: D:\tfsAgent_work\folder\folder\Project_2\error CS0006: metadata file '\folder\folder\bin\debug\net461\Project_4.dll' could not be found"***

Same error, but for Project_3, referencing Project_4 as well.

By looking at the build log I see that **Project_4 is built after Projects 2 and 3**, thus the file is not there yet.

I tried different options:

•adding the references in project.json

•using Project references

•Solution properties -> Project dependencies...

•manually reorder the projects in API.sln file.

No difference.

```
**WebApi_Project_1.json:**

 {
  "dependencies": {
    "Project_2": "1.0.0-*",
    "Project_3": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.1.0"
  },

 "tools": {
     "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
   },

   "frameworks": {
      "net461": {}
   },

   "buildOptions": {
     "emitEntryPoint": true,
     "preserveCompilationContext": true,
     "platform": "x86",
     "copyToOutput": {
       "include": [
         "Folder/Folder/Folder/*.xsd",
         "Folder/Folder/Folder/*.xml"
       ]
     }
   },

   "publishOptions": {
     "include": [
       "wwwroot",
       "Views",
       "Areas/**/Views",
       "appsettings.json",
       "web.config"
     ]
   },

   "scripts": {
     "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %     publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
   }
 }


 **Project_2.json**

 {
   "dependencies": {
     "Project_4": "1.0.0.0"
   },

   "buildOptions": {"platform": "x86"},

   "frameworks": {
     "net461": {}
     }

   }


**Project_3.json**
{

  "buildOptions": { "platform": "x86" },

  "dependencies": {

    "Project_4": "1.0.0.0"

  },

   "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}


**Project_4.json**

{
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "buildOptions": { "platform": "x86" },
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use XAML build or vNext build? How's your build definition like? Try to use MSBuild command line on your build agent machine to build the solution in the source directory of build agent, to see what result you'll get.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue, please post detailed log.

Comment: Thank you, Cece for your efforts. I managed to make it work by changing the MSBuild argument of "Visual Studio Build Task" in TFS, from "/t:Rebuild" to "/t:Build".  Then it worked. At the beginning I was worried that it might used an old instance of the library, but after a number of checks (incl. the build order in the log) I am certain now that it works correctly and the build order is correct. Don't have explanation why this happens.